# How to effectively map between Enum in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have two Enums,

```
enum class EnumKey

enum class EnumValue
```

and I already have a mapping from `EnumKey` to `EnumValue`.

```
fun EnumKey.toEnumValue(): EnumValue = 
    when(this) {
    EnumA.KEY1 -> EnumValue.VALUE1
    EnumA.KEY2 -> EnumValue.VALUE2
    ...
    ...
    EnumA.KEY1000 -> EnumValue.VALUE1000
    }
```

Now I need to have an another mapping from `EnumValue` to `EnumKey`.

Is using a `Map` and its reversed map created by `associateBy` the best way to do it? Or is there any other better ways?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use Sealed Class? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html#sealed-classes, Enum class and sealed class is quite similar. A set of values for an enumeration type is also restricted as a closed class.
The only difference enum can have only a single sample, but covered a class that can have multiple instances of a subclass. :)

Comment: The values are limited, and can be certain during compile time, so Enum is more suitable.

Comment: Ah i see, but enum could have memory problems in runtime, i usually use constants in this case. Constants are super concise as well. They hold a single value and give it a name. They are also extremely lightweight.

Comment: Is this a 1:1 mapping, and if so, why are there two enums instead of 1?

Comment: It's a 1 to 1 mapping. The reason to keep them seperate is because they are in different domains.

Comment: you can have a `Map` of mappings. you can use the same in both directions

Answer (score 1):

If the enum values are somehow connected by name and they're as large as in your example, then I would advise using something like `EnumValue.values().filter { it.name.contains(...) }` or using regex.

If they aren't and the connection needs to be stated explicitly then I would use an object (so it's a singleton like the enums themselves) and have this mapping hidden there:

```
object EnumsMapping {

    private val mapping = mapOf(
        EnumKey.A to EnumValue.X,
        EnumKey.B to EnumValue.Y,
        EnumKey.C to EnumValue.Z,
    )
....
```

and next, have the associated values available by functions in this object like:

```
fun getEnumValue(enumKey: EnumKey) = mapping[enumKey]

and

fun getEnumKey(enumValue: EnumValue) = mapping.filterValues { it == enumValue }.keys.single()
```

If it's often used or the enums are huge, and you're troubled by the performance of filtering the values every time, then you can create the association in the second way, just like you've proposed:

```
private val mapping2 = mapping.toList()
        .associate { it.second to it.first }
```

and then have the second function just access this new mapping.

Writing the extension functions like you've provided, but using this object, will result in cleaner code and having the raw association still in one place.

Comment: So how's the performance of `associate`? If I have a huge mapping list, would it block a lot if I run in main thread?

Comment: Wouldn't worry too much about performance. I've run this associate function 1000 times on a map with 1000 entries and it took around 170ms on a standard laptop, i5. So avg of 0,17 ms for creating a map in the another direction.

Comment: On the other hand 1000 searches through proposed `filterValues` take around 30ms, so we can estimate that single search is 5 times faster than reassociation of the whole map. So you have to decide what is more often used and whether to sacrifice some code readbility with two maps or not.